# How to calculate time difference between two dates in the same column in pandas dataframe and factor in business days

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe in pandas that reads data from csv file. I have a column event_dattim that has date&time in str format. I want to calculate the difference in miliseconds between two datetime as in most cases difference is only in miliseconds. I have tried the below code and keep getting 
ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed.

The is for data with millions of records.

```
key_date    key_time    key_milsec  recordcd    crnode  event_dattim
6/1/2019    00.00.05    0   T   1   2019-05-31-11.00.05.731871
6/1/2019    00.00.24    430500  T   1   2019-06-01-00.00.24.552302
6/1/2019    00.00.24    430500  T   1   2019-06-04-02.54.56.658875
6/1/2019    00.00.24    430500  T   1   2019-06-04-10.35.54.820187
6/1/2019    00.00.24    430500  T   1   2019-06-04-10.37.53.829744
6/1/2019    00.00.27    453440  T   1   2019-06-01-00.00.27.553880
6/1/2019    00.00.27    453440  T   1   2019-06-04-02.54.56.668795
6/1/2019    00.00.27    453440  T   1   2019-06-04-07.40.31.163718
6/1/2019    00.00.27    453440  T   1   2019-06-04-07.41.45.995590
6/1/2019    00.00.27    453440  T   1   2019-06-05-02.52.35.476701
6/1/2019    00.00.27    453440  T   1   2019-06-05-12.47.31.263512
6/1/2019    00.00.31    70480   T   1   2019-06-01-00.00.31.149815
6/1/2019    00.00.31    70480   T   1   2019-06-04-02.54.56.676816
6/1/2019    00.00.31    70480   T   1   2019-06-04-10.35.40.414527
```

I tried with below code.

df['Time_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['event_dattim'].astype(str)).diff().dt.total_seconds().multiply(1000).BDay()

I want output to get results in a new column as below

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA49U.png)

Comment: if you could post some sample data (not an image) it would help others to help troubleshoot

Comment: Thanks. I am new to stack overflow. Still learning things

Comment: can you explain what the data in the 'event_dattim' column means? I don't recognize the format...

Comment: it is in format= '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the below code.

```
df1['event_dattim'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['event_dattim'], format=r'%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f')

df1['difference'] = df2.groupby(['key_date','key_time','key_milsec','recordcd','crnode'])['event_dattim'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: This gives me total seconds between grouped series but I am still unable to minus weekends and holidays